# Why NativeScript's default build produces a combined 18mb apk

Tags: nativescript

Earlier before webpack the default build of nativescript is about 12 mb. And all of a sudden with the introduction of webpack why default hello world app build apk increased its size to 18mb.

I rarely use Nativescript and after a long time i came back here. Now my project is finished,

and with below command for apk and aab

> tns build android --bundle --env.uglify --env.aot  --release --key-store-path E:\myproj\mykey.keystore --key-store-password a1234 --key-store-alias a1234  --key-store-alias-password a1234
>
> --aab --copy-to C:\Users\RTX\Desktop\plus2.aab

the size of the project is `36 mb` in both `apk and aab` formats.

Earlier i have done a big project with lot of dependencies and it was only 26Mb in size.

But now with only below 8 plugins, and `app` folder of size 2.77 MB. The `apk` size is `36Mb`.

```
    "@nstudio/nativescript-floatingactionbutton": "xxx",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "xxx",
    "nativescript-pager": "xxx",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "xxx",
    "nativescript-permissions": "xxx",
    "nativescript-phone": "xxx",
    "nativescript-toast": "xxx",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "xxx",
```

Atleast earlier it was 26 mb it is somewhat ok. but for a very simple app which contains just 50+ files and some 10 to 12 images which totals in 2.77MB app folder 36Mb apk is not an acceptable thing. So can any one help me on this.

Update :-
Web pack report

```
Stat
Show chunks:
All (2.99 MB)
vendor.js (2.63 MB)
bundle.js (352.37 KB)
runtime.js (13.87 KB)

parsed 
Show chunks:
All (7.24 MB)
vendor.js (6.27 MB)
bundle.js (984.15 KB)
runtime.js (13.87 KB)

Gzipped 
Show chunks:
All (1.2 MB)
vendor.js (1.07 MB)
bundle.js (126.64 KB)
runtime.js (4.5 KB)
```

[apk analyser details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJs0W.jpg)

[in depth details of size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ab0T.jpg)

> Final Expectation:-

- Because of Pdf plugin i used the build was taking `9 mb extra`. Is there any alternative solution for pdf so that i can reduce the app size.
- Also i found that default hello world build was `18 mb` which was earlier `12 mb`. So, is there any explanation for this.
- Can anyone give a rough example of `size variation of app` in different devices if `aab file` is uploaded to google playstore. lets assume `aab build size is 36 mb`

Comment: Did you try checking the webpack size map, see which files / packages are consuming more space in the bundle?

Comment: @Manoj I dont find webpack map file nowhere. how to check that ?

Comment: Checkout [generating-webpack-report](https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack#generating-webpack-report) section from docs.

Comment: If you believe your bundle size is decent and something possibly with native libraries, you can use the [APK analyser](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer) to see what is taking the space.

Comment: @Manoj i updated the Report details above. What to do with it ?

Comment: @Manoj i uploaded the Apk analyser details image. Kindly look at it. and tell me how to reduce the app size.

Comment: Did you try removing the PDF plugin, see if that makes a difference in the binary size?

Comment: @Manoj pdf is very important thing. without that my app will crash. how to remove it i have used it so many places.

Comment: I'm not proposing it as a solution, suggesting it as a tracking method. You got to do what's needed to track whats exactly eating the space. In my experience with PDFs on Android, that's what usually eats a lot of space. You may run separate build for each architecture to reduce your bundle size.

Comment: Keep in mind that by default, you are building for multiple architectures(X86, X86_64, armv7, armv8). If you want to decrease the size significantly,  you could use ABI Splits and publish multiple APKs (for different architectures and for different screen densities). https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/android-abi-split

Comment: @Manoj You are right pdf was consuming 9mb of space. may be on aab release. for different mobiles the size will get reduce. thank you

Comment: @Manoj i have updated my question. kindly look at `Final Expectation` section at bottom and answer if it's worthy.